# I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when i use a external ja file with anonymus fuction

Tags: javascript

**** External main.js ****

```
(function(){
    var firebase = app_fireBase;  

    const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtUserName') 
    const txtPass = document.getElementById('txtPass') 
    const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin') 
    const btnSingUp = document.getElementById('btnSingUp') 
    const btnlogOut = document.getElementById('btnLogOut') 

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e =>{
        console.log('Works!!');
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const password = txtPass.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        //Sign In 
        const promise = auth.singInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    })
}());
```

**** when i use the same method in the html or in a external Js file without the (fuction (){}()) all works well!! ****

**** I see this example in a Firebase Tutorial Help Please ****

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not getting the id properly from the html element. Make sure

```
btnLogin
```

is the same as the id in your html.
Has to be exactly the same.